# Assign Tax Class to Products

Tags: sql, database, magento, e-commerce

I have (what I think is) a simple problem with my Magento tax classes. I have around 400 products in my shop and only 20 of them have a tax class assigned to it. I checked my database and the table "catalog_product_index_price" and all the products with the working tax have tax_class_id = 1 and all the not working ones have tax_class_id = 0.

So I thought I'll just update every product to `tax_class_id = 1` and I'm done, but as soon as I re-indexed my prices in the Magento back-end the products got `tax_class_id = 0` again.

Somewhere there must be a default, but I can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

`catalog_product_index_price` is an index table, which is populated during reindexation process. It means that it pulls data from other tables and group them in this table for further use. That's why your changes were overridden after the reindex.

If you want to change **tax_class_id** for your products, the easiest option would be to use *Mass Update** functionality in your admin panel. Open Manage Products section, select all products (select all), choose **Update Attributes** from action dropdown, and you'll be able to change `Tax Class` for all the products at once.

Comment: I have been using Magento for years and didn't realise this existed - argh!!!! +1

Answer (score 0):

Try change it by hand by going to Catalog -> Manage Product -> Click on one -> Prices -> Tax Class.

Then have a look how it changes in the back end.

```
select * from catalog_product_index_price where entity_id = [[product_id]];
```

Best bet from here is to trace the SQL statement by changing pdo debug on by logging the sql statements: http://yauhen.yakimovich.info/blog/2011/03/21/log-all-sql-queries-in-magento/